# compare iPhone5 and iPhone5S with coding

Tags: iphone-5

As we've started to work with iOS7 - and facing some issue during coding - i.e. how we can compare iPhone5 and iPhone 5S - So that we can check either the system is 32bit or 64bit and can use variables accordingly.

Comment: just use `NSInteger`/`NSUInteger`/`CGFloat`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this via *compile time conditionals*, there's a new "`__arm64__`" conditonal defined that is now available for 64-bit compiled code.

Presumably "`__arm__`" is what gets defined for 32-bit device code.

You'll also likely notice there's a new available architecture in Xcode alongside "armv6, armv7 and armv7s", that being "arm64".

So you could do something like this:

```
#ifdef __arm64__
    NSLog( @"we're running 64-bit");
else
    NSLog( @"32-bit iphone code");
#endif
```